# Firebase Storage: 100% of your quota has been used – upgrade to ensure there is no service disruption

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I've been using firebase for testing purposes and haven't uploaded many images (I'm using the free version). I recently noticed that I no longer have access to the Firebase Storage because 100% of the bandwidth quota has been used (see screenshot below). Am I forced to upgrade to a paid version in order to gain access to Firebase Storage again or is there another way around this? Also, what would be easy implementations into my project to make sure I can avoid such a high bandwidth consumption in the future? (only a dozen images have been uploaded to storage so far).

[image]

Comment: What is size of your images and how many times did you download them?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the image sizes, most were just phone screenshots. Also not sure about the amount of times downloaded

Comment: Can you check what Dharmaraj asked you?